# How to set UIButton to touch coordinates

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, nsuserdefaults

I have UIWebView and i use UILongPressGesture for get touch coordinates. I saved these coordinates in `NSUserDefaults` then get it later. I need to display a button in touch coordinates position. Is it possible?

LongPress:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTest:)];
    [tap setDelegate:self];
    [wbCont addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

saving coordinates:

```
- (void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"coordinate is %f %f", [sender locationInView:wbCont].x, [sender locationInView:wbCont].y);

    float xcor = [sender locationInView:wbCont].x;
    float ycor = [sender locationInView:wbCont].y;

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userDefaults setFloat:xcor forKey:@"xpoint"];
    [userDefaults setFloat:ycor forKey:@"ypoint"];

     [userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Get it from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    float xValue = [data floatForKey:@"xpoint"];
    float yValue = [data floatForKey:@"ypoint"];
```

I need to display a button on if x & y position:

```
if(xValue && yValue){

        NSLog(@"xvalue is %f",xValue);
         NSLog(@"yval is %f",yValue);

        button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button1 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(click1:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button1 setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // button1.frame = CGRectMake(240.0, 20.0, 60.0, 40.0);

   [wbcont addSubview:button1];

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Just add button1.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, 60.0, 40.0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update button **X** and **Y** position according to `xValue` and  `yValue` value that you got it.

Set frame of button

```
button1.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, 60.0, 40.0);
```

Comment: sorry ,, i can not get you.. can you please elaborate your issue ??

Comment: Add your button on webView

Comment: If i use wbCont.scrollView it's working. But button showing on wrong coordinates. why?

Comment: Got it. If i use locationInView:wbCont.scrollView, it's working